# get data from xml using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web, service

I'm trying to get some data from xml using pandas. Currently I have "working" code, and by working i mean it almost work.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://degra.wi.pb.edu.pl/rozklady/webservices.php?"


response = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

tables = soup.find_all('tabela_rozklad')

tags = ['dzien', 'godz', 'ilosc', 'tyg', 'id_naucz', 'id_sala',
'id_prz', 'rodz', 'grupa', 'id_st', 'sem', 'id_spec']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for table in tables:
    all = map(lambda x: table.find(x).text, tags)
    df = df.append([all])

df.columns = tags

a = df[(df.sem == "1")]
a = a[(a.id_spec == "0")]
a = a[(a.dzien == "1")]
print(a)
```

So I'm getting error on "a = df[(df.sem == "1")]" which is :

File "pandas\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4443)

File "pandas\index.pyx", line 161, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4289)

File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13733)

File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13687)

As i read other stacks questions I saw people suggest using df.loc so i modyfied this line into

```
a = df.loc[(df.sem == "1")]
```

Now code compile but the results show like this line doesn't exists. Need to mention that the problem is with the "sem" tag only. Rest works perfectly but unfortunately i need to use exactly this tag. If anyone could explain what i causing this error and how to fix it I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ignore_index=True` to [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) for avoid duplicated `index` and then need select column `sem` by `[]`, because function [`sem`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sem.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for table in tables:
    all = map(lambda x: table.find(x).text, tags)
    df = df.append([all], ignore_index=True)

df.columns = tags
#print (df)

a = df[(df['sem'] == '1') & (df.id_spec == "0") & (df.dzien == "1")]
```

```
print(a)
    dzien godz ilosc tyg id_naucz id_sala id_prz rodz grupa id_st sem id_spec
0       1    1     2   0       52      79     13    W     1    13   1       0
1       1    3     2   0       12      79     32    W     1    13   1       0
2       1    5     2   0       52      65     13   Ćw     1    13   1       0
3       1   11     2   0      201       3     70   Ćw    10    13   1       0
4       1    5     2   0       36      78     13   Ps     5    13   1       0
5       1    5     2   1       18      32    450   Ps     3    13   1       0
6       1    5     2   2       18      32    450   Ps     4    13   1       0
7       1    7     2   1       18      32    450   Ps     7    13   1       0
8       1    7     2   2       18      32    450   Ps     8    13   1       0
9       1    7     2   0       66      65    104   Ćw     1    13   1       0
10      1    7     2   0      283       3    104   Ćw     5    13   1       0
11      1    7     2   0      346       5    104   Ćw     8    13   1       0
12      1    7     2   0      184      29     13   Ćw     7    13   1       0
13      1    9     2   0       66      65    104   Ćw     2    13   1       0
14      1    9     2   0      346       5     70   Ćw     8    13   1       0
15      1    9     1   0       73       3    203   Ćw     9    13   1       0
16      1   10     1   0       73       3    203   Ćw    10    13   1       0
17      1    9     2   0      184      19     13   Ps    13    13   1       0
18      1   11     2   0      184      19     13   Ps    14    13   1       0
19      1   11     2   0       44      65     13   Ćw     9    13   1       0
87      1    9     2   0      201      54    463    W     1    17   1       0
88      1    3     2   0       36      29     13   Ćw     2    17   1       0
89      1    3     2   0      211       5     70   Ćw     1    17   1       0
90      1    5     2   0      211       5     70   Ćw     2    17   1       0
91      1    7     2   0       36      78     13   Ps     4    17   1       0
105     1    1     2   1       11      16     32   Ps     2    18   1       0
106     1    1     2   2       11      16     32   Ps     3    18   1       0
107     1    3     2   0       51       3    457    W     1    18   1       0
110     1    5     2   2       11      16     32   Ps     1    18   1       0
111     1    7     2   0       91      64     97   Ćw     2    18   1       0
112     1    5     2   0      283       3    457   Ćw     2    18   1       0
254     1    5     1   0       12      29     32   Ćw     6    13   1       0
255     1    6     1   0       12      29     32   Ćw     5    13   1       0
462     1    7     2   0       98       1    486    W     1    19   1       0
463     1    9     1   0       91       1    484    W     1    19   1       0
487     1    5     2   0      116      19     13   Ps     1    17   1       0
488     1    7     2   0      116      19     13   Ps     2    17   1       0
498     1    5     2   0        0       0    431   Ps     2    17   1       0
502     1    5     2   0        0       0    431   Ps    15    13   1       0
503     1    5     2   0        0       0    431   Ps    16    13   1       0
504     1    5     2   0        0       0    431   Ps    19    13   1       0
505     1    5     2   0        0       0    431   Ps    20    13   1       0
531     1   13     2   0      350      79    493    W     1    13   1       0
532     1   13     2   0      350      79    493    W     2    17   1       0
533     1   13     2   0      350      79    493    W     1    18   1       0
```

Comment: This works really well, but can You explain why my code wasn't ?

Comment: thank for accepting. So it is problem with code words, so if your column is `sum`, `mean`, `count`, `sem` you cannot select by `df.sum`, `df.count`, `df.mean`, `df.sem`, because all of them are pandas function [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html), [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html)... So for this column need select by `df['sum']`, `df['mean']` ... `df['sem']`.

Comment: see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access) - check `warning` - `The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing method name, e.g. s.min is not allowed.`